# Extruding two objects the exact same amount but the results are different

Tags: mesh, geometry, extrude

Please see the images.

I extruded two planes each exactly 1 metre along local Z (mannually typed in -1 in the panel), but the resulting extrusion amounts are very different

Both planes before extruding:
[image: before extruding]

Object 1 Extruded:
[image: object1 extruded]

Object 2 Extruded:
[image: object2 extruded]

What's going on here?

Comment: Have both objects the scale applied with `Ctrl`+`A`? Because it looks as if you have scaled down the upper object and it still has a scale < 1. To see the "real" median position relative to the world coordinates switch from _Local_ to _Global_. The local position is relative to the objects origin, rotation and scale.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thank you, i applied the scale and problem solved